# I am trying to open a process as a different user in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to open a process as a different user with PowerShell.
I use the following script.

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$User2 = "MyPc\User2"

$Credential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User2, $Password

Start-Process cmd.exe -Credential $Credential -WorkingDirectory C:\
```

User 2 has admin rights.
Cmd is open. When I'm writing `whoami` it returns "User2". But I can't access to a directory.
The error message is "Access Denied".

OK...  I think there must be an access problem.

I run as user2 cmd with a right click, and I access to the directory.

I don't see where my error is.

Comment: Add `-Verb RunAs` to the `Start-Process` command

Comment: Beware that elevation will ignore the working directory you specified (for security reasons). You need to pass the working directory as a parameter and then change the working directory in the script.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I tried `Start-Process cmd.exe -Verbose RunAs -Credential $Credential -WorkingDirectory C:\ ` and i have the same result.

Comment: I run this : `Start-Process powershell -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList '-command &{Start-Process cmd -verb runas }' -WorkingDirectory c:\` and it's work. 
Thank for your help.